# Getting Postgres Table Not Found Error with @ReadOnly Annotation in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, annotations

I am getting the error `PSQLException: ERROR: relation "schema.tableName" does not exist.`

I have a `GET` API in spring which fetches data from a table. This API internally uses a custom method to access data using JpaReporitory. This custom method is annotated with `@ReadOnly` and `@Transactional` annotations since this API only fetches data from table. This gives me the table not found error.

But when I remove the `@ReadOnly` annotation, the API works just fine.

Below are the signatures of the said API and the custom method that it uses:

**API:**

```
@GetMapping("/houses/{houseId}/furnitures")
    public List<Furnitures> getFurnitureslist(@PathVariable("houseId") long houseId) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        return this.houseService.getFurnituresList(houseId);
    }
```

**Custom method:**

```
    @Transactional
    @ReadOnly
    public List<Asset> getTripPicklist(long tripId){

        //Bunch of read operations using jpa repository.
    }
```

This gives me an error trace as below:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "schema.tableName" does not exist
```

But when I remove the `@ReadOnly` annotation from my custom method, the API works fine and I am able fetch the expected results from the database. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you specify fully qualified name of @ReadOnly annotation that you are using? By the way @Transactional(readOnly = true) will does same job ...

Comment: @AmitPatil Just checked and it is actually a custom annotation developed by one of the previous developers. But Using @Transactional(readOnly = true) gives the same error.